# Jquery Passing checkbox values

Tags: jquery, parameters, autocomplete

Im trying to get the selected value of a 2 radio options (1 & 2)

and pass it into a auto complete extraParams: value

so far i have this

```
extraParams: { search_option: $('input[name=search_option]:checked').val() },
```

problem is if the radio is changes the value is not updated.

Any ideas as how i can do this

Thanks

Comment: Amended my answer, hope it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify a callback to a function otherwise that value is locked into the autocomplete when you initialize the plugin.

```
extraParams: {
         search_option : function() { 
                return $('input[name=search_option]:checked').val(); 
         }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks redsquare. I thought it would need to be a function. Having a little trouble with the syntax however as im new to jquery.

Getting Error: missing : after property id? How to fix this thanks

Comment: hmmm, i think because its already inside a function maybe the problem.

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 jQuery(function($){
   
 $("#keywords").autocomplete(
   "/ajax.search.php",
   
   {

    extraParams: {
          search_option : function() { 
                $('input[name=search_option]:checked').val(); 
            }
    },
    
    delay:10,
    minChars:2,

Syntax error is gone but o get no value. Any more ideas, thanks?

Comment: jQuery(function($){ $("#keywords").autocomplete( "/ajax.search.php", { extraParams: { search_option : function() { return $('input[name=search_option]:checked').val(); } }, delay:10, minChars:2

Comment: yeah your right sorry i messed that.  Perfect thanks so much :)